# Adding an int array to a list without it only takes the last version of the array

Tags: c#, arrays, list, int

This is a simplified version of the problem im trying to solve. Im trying to add an `int[]` to a `List`, but it updates all the arrays in the `List` with the one from the last iteration. Why is that? And how does I solve this problem? This isn't a problem if it's just 1 `int` for example.

```
intArray = new int[9];

for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
{
    intArray[i] = i;
}

Test.Add(intArray);

for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
{
     intArray[i] = i * 2;
}

Test.Add(intArray);

foreach (var item in Test)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
   {
       Console.WriteLine(item[i]);
   }
}

Console.ReadKey();
}

public static int[] intArray { get; set; }
public static List<int[]> Test = new List<int[]>();
```

Comment: You're only ever creating a single array. Your list contains lots of references to that same array. Now's a good time to learn about reference types :) See http://jonskeet.uk/csharp/references.html for example.

Comment: After each `Add`, instantiate a new array by repeating this line `intArray = new int[9];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `new` keyword you create `intArray` only once. Then there is only one reference. After that you add `intArray` reference to collection `List` for multiple times.

Try this,

```
intArray = new int[9];

for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
{
     intArray[i] = i;
}

Test.Add(intArray);

intArray = new int[9]; // create new intArray here

for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
{
     intArray[i] = i * 2;
}

Test.Add(intArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

after u added your intArray object into your arraylist ,simply create another  object of that

intArray = new int[length];

hope it will works